# How to draw a spritebatch without Color?

Tags: xna, 2d, textures, draw, xna-4.0

I'm drawing a Texture2D like this

```
//background_texture is white in color
spritebatch.Draw(content.Load<Texture2D>("background_texture"), 
     new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100),
     Color.Red)
```

The texture is white; however, on screen it's displayed as red.

Why is the draw method requiring a Color?
How does one simply draw the texture, and only the texture without having Color.something distort the graphic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at the documentation here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433986.aspx

you want to try Color.White, that additional parameter of a color typically refers to a tint, while a white "tint" should display the sprite without a tint

Comment: Requiring a tint is plain silly in my mind. Why not just have another overload method without a Color parameter, so we can have some options here, what's the with unnecessary Color.white? And what if someone wanted a white tint? But thanks though

Comment: What do you believe "a white tint" is?

Answer (score 1):

Color.White does not change the color of your image. Use

```
spritebatch.Draw(content.Load<Texture2D>("background_texture"), 
 new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100),
 Color.White);
```

Instead of Color.Red, which applies a tint.
Note: Be careful. Intellisense will want to make this Color.*Wheat*, so be sure to type the first 3 letters before you hit space.

Answer (score -1):

Color.White is uneccesary because in default sprite shader it looks like this:

PixelShader....
{
....

return Texture * Color;
}

Where color is Color that is given from Vertex shader defined by that Color in spritebatch.Draw... if it would be null, black, it would create invisible sprites. Whole point is that by this you set vertex color of each vertex that is used as multiplicative to texture you set for sprite.

Comment: How's that "unnecessary" if it's a mandatory API parameter?